# Wide PlotMarkers Option For ListPlot?

Tags: plotting

0

I am creating some Listplots of some data with the following bit of code:

```
bbbarexpmasses = {{1, 9.4449}, {2, 9.8999}, {3, 10.023}, {4, 
   10.163}, {5, 10.260}, {6, 10.355}, {7, 10.579}}

bbbartheorymasses = {{1, 9.4258128}, {2, 9.884308}, {3, 
   9.9751791}, {4, 10.145617}, {5, 10.270137}, {6, 10.197768}, {7, 
   10.430176}}

BBbarcomparison = 
 ListPlot[{bbbarexpmasses, bbbartheorymasses}, 
  PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, Medium}, ImageSize -> Large, 
  Frame -> All, 
  Ticks -> {{{1, "1S"}, {2, "1P"}, {3, "2S"}, {4, "1D"}, {5, 
      "2P"}, {6, "3S"}, {7, "4S"}}, {9.4449, 9.8999, 10.023, 10.163, 
     10.260, 10.355, 10.579}}]
```

which works fine and produces the following plot:[image: BBbar]

But now I would like to have the PlotMarkers to be wider, more like the markers in this plot. [image: masses]

Is there an option in Mathematica to do something like this? Thanks.

Comment: That plot looks more like a `BarChart` in my opinion, that should make this type of plot easier. You can then use [`ChartElementFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ChartElementFunction.html) to draw the lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `PlotMarkers` to specify your shape, add `Scaled[]` with each shape to have the right size, and use `PlotStyle` to specify the color of each series. Because of the large shapes, the `PlotRange` should be specified manually.

`Table` used to generate `PlotMarkers` shapes, each with some variation.

```
ListPlot[{bbbarexpmasses, bbbartheorymasses}, ImageSize -> Large, 
 Frame -> All, 
 Ticks -> {{{1, "1S"}, {2, "1P"}, {3, "2S"}, {4, "1D"}, {5, "2P"}, {6,
      "3S"}, {7, "4S"}}, {9.4449, 9.8999, 10.023, 10.163, 10.260, 
    10.355, 10.579}}, 
 PlotMarkers -> 
  Table[{Graphics[Rectangle[{0, 0}, {10, i}, RoundingRadius -> .7]], 
    Scaled[.02*i + .1]}, {i, {1, 1.2}}], 
 PlotStyle -> {GrayLevel[.3], GrayLevel[.7]}, 
 PlotRange -> {{.5, 7.5}, Automatic}]
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this is very useful!